# Dynamically interpolating string with specific object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component where I have a list of objects and I want to pass in a single input parameter that describes the route that should be navigated to when any specific row is clicked.

Something like the below:

```
    //Some sort of object may have an 'id' field in some cases (but not in other cases... if it didn't I would pass in a different string below)
    @Input()
    listData: any[]; 
    @Input()
    link: string; // Input of something like "/List/Detail/${row.id}"

    rowClick(row: any){
      //Grab row.id and interpolate it so result is "/List/Detail/1"
      ???
      router.navigate([url]);
    }
```

Seems like it should be simple, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

The idea here is that my list items will sometimes link to one page and sometimes link to a different page depending on the 'link' parameter.

Comment: You could use lodash _.template https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template

Comment: const url = `${row.url}/${row.id}`;

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall you must remove the ${row.id} part btw

Comment: I'm not really sure the structure of the Obj so just put the example in a string literal.

Comment: I already have lodash in the project so I'll give that a try.  Looks like it should work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash `_.template`:

```js
const compiledTemplate = _.template(this.link);

compiledTemplate({ row });
```

Using Javascript:

```js
const linkParts = this.link.split('/');

linkParts.pop();
linkParts.push(row.id);
const linkWithRowId = linkParts.join('/');
```